# results from "Google Vizier: A Service for Black-Box Optimization"

Tags: optimization, gaussian

In [Google Vizier: A Service for Black-Box Optimization](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/de//pubs/archive/46180.pdf) it is show what kind of optimizers google uses internally.
Figure 6 shows some benchmark results compared to Random Search. Am I right in understanding that "GP Bandit" has better results as "CMA-ES" in 8 Dimensions? So is a lower number better?

[image: Figure 6 from the paper]

Thank you